# How to duplicate records, modify and add them to same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I got some question and hopefully you can help me out. :)

What I have is a table like this:

```
ID  Col1        Col2        ReverseID
1   Number 1    Number A    
2   Number 2    Number B    
3   Number 3    Number C
```

What I want to achieve is:

- Create duplicate of every record with switched columns and add them to original table
- Add the ID of the duplicate to ReverseID column of original record and vice-versa

So the new table should look like:

```
ID  Col1        Col2        ReverseID
1   Number 1    Number A    4
2   Number 2    Number B    5
3   Number 3    Number C    6
4   Number A    Number 1    1
5   Number B    Number 2    2
6   Number C    Number 3    3
```

What I've done so far was working with temporary table:

```
SELECT * INTO #tbl
FROM myTable

UPDATE #tbl
SET Col1 = Col2,
    Col2 = Col1,
    ReverseID = ID

INSERT INTO DUPLICATEtable(
        Col1,
        Col2,
        ReverseID
)

SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       ReverseID
FROM #tbl
```

In this example code I used a secondary table just for making sure I do not compromise the original data records.

I think I could skip the SET-part and change the columns in the last SELECT statement to achieve the same, but I am not sure.

Anyway - with this I am ending up at:

```
ID  Col1        Col2        ReverseID
1   Number 1    Number A    
2   Number 2    Number B    
3   Number 3    Number C    
4   Number A    Number 1    1
5   Number B    Number 2    2
6   Number C    Number 3    3
```

So the question remains: How do I get the ReverseIDs correctly added to original records?

As my SQL knowledge is pretty low I am almost sure, this is not the simplest way of doing things, so I hope you guys & girls can enlighten me and lead me to a more elegant solution.

Thank you in advance!

br
mrt

#### Edit:

I try to illustrate my initial problem, so this posting gets long. ;)

[image: ED]
.

First of all: My frontend does not allow any SQL statements, I have to focus on classes, attributes, relations.

**First root cause:**
Instances of a class B (B1, B2, B3, ...) are linked together in class Relation, these are many-to-many relations of same class. My frontend does not allow join tables, so that's a workaround.

Stating a user adds a relation with B1 as first side (I just called it 'left') and B2 as second side (right):

Navigating from B1, there will be two relations showing up (FK_Left, FK_Right), but only one of them will contain a value (let's say FK_Left).

Navigating from B2, the value will be only listed in the other relation (FK_Right).
So from the users side, there are always two relations displayed, but it depends on how the record was entered, if one can find the data behind relation_left or relation_right.
That's no practicable usability.

If I had all records with vice-versa partners, I can just hide one of the relations and the user sees all information behind **one** relation, regardless how it was entered.

**Second root cause:**
The frontend provides some matrix view, which gets the relation class as input and displays left partners in columns and right partners in rows.

Let's say I want to see all instances of A in columns and their partners in rows, this is only possible, if all relations regarding the instances of A  are entered the same way, e.g. all A-instances as left partner.

The matrix view shall be freely filterable regarding rows and columns, so if I had duplicate relations, I can filter on any of the partners in rows and columns.

sorry for the long text, I hope that made my situation a bit clearer.

Comment: is it a one time thing? or will you be doing it periodically?

Comment: What are you trying to solve here? Storing the same data twice is well...redundant. And now you are making each existing row point to the same row but in reverse. This has a lot of red flags all over the place. Why not simply create a view that "reverses" the data? This would be pretty simple with an update statement after the second insert but it just sounds like a better solution makes more sense here.

Comment: @sabhari It will be a one time thing one productive machine to get old record-sets updated, all new records will be automatically created in the "new" way

Comment: @SeanLange The numbers in the columns are relation-IDs to other tables and this is some kind of m:n relation table. The frontend shows the relations uni-directional, so you have to start at a certain node (depending which was first entered) to see the relation.
As improvement, Users shall be able to insert relations bi-directional, that's why I want to copy every set. In case of deletion/modification I can use the ReverseID to easily find the duplicate and do the same with duplicate.

Comment: But making two copies of the data is so brittle. This is a bad idea. Create a view that reverses the data instead. Or just modify your joins to this table to allow using OR.

Comment: Yes, I do not feel confident with this "solution" too, but I do not know how to make it better. The frontend does not allow any SQL statements, I can only use one table as input. I will illustrate this and add it to the initial question.

Comment: hmm, as I see you are clueless like me, so I will go on with this "solution" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just using a view instead of trying to create and maintain two copies of the same data. Then you just select from the view instead of the base table.

```
create view MyReversedDataView as

select ID
    , Col1
    , Col2
from MyTable

UNION ALL

select ID
    , Col2
    , Col1
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this kind of thing is to start with a SELECT that gets the data you need. In this case you need a resultset with Col1, Col2, reverseid.

```
SELECT Col2 Col1, Col1 Col1, ID reverseid
  INTO #tmp   FROM myTable;
```

Convince yourself it's correct -- swapped column values etc.

Then do this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Col1, col2, reverseid)
SELECT Col1, Col2, reverseid FROM #tmp;
```

If you're doing this from a GUI like ssms, don't forget to `DROP TABLE #tmp;`

BUT, you can get the same result with a pure query, without duplicating rows.  Why do it this way?

1. You save the wasted space for the reversed rows.
2. You always get the reversed rows up to the last second, even if you forget to run the process for reversing and inserting them into the table.
3. There's no consistency problem if you insert or delete rows from the table.

Here's how you might do this.

```
 SELECT Col1, Col2, null reverseid FROM myTable
  UNION ALL
 SELECT Col2 Col1, Col1 Col2, ID reverseid FROM myTable;
```

You can even make it into a view and use it as if it were a table going forward.

```
CREATE VIEW myTableWithReversals AS
SELECT Col1, Col2, null reverseid FROM myTable
 UNION ALL
SELECT Col2 Col1, Col1 Col2, ID reverseid FROM myTable;
```

Then you can say `SELECT * FROM myTableWithReversals WHERE Col1 = 'value'` etc.

Comment: your first statement throws error `Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'col1' in table '#tmp' is specified more than once.` 
I tried to use `SELECT Col2 Col1, Col1 Col2, ID reverseid` instead, is this what you've meant?

Comment: My `Col1` column names are placeholders for the purpose of giving an example. You would replace them with your own column names.

Comment: yes, but in your first codeblock you selected `Col1` three times, which I think is not as intended?

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that the `id` column is auto-incremented.  Then, you can do this in two steps:

```
insert into myTable (Col1, Col2, reverseid)
    select col2, col1, id
    from myTable t
    order by id;  -- ensures that they go in in the right order
```

This inserts the new ids with the right `reverseid`.  Now we have to update the previous values:

```
update t
    set reverseid = tr.id
    from myTable t join
         myTable tr
         on tr.reverseid = t.id;
```

Note that no temporary tables are needed.

Comment: I do not understand you last code block, may you please explain it a little bit? I get an error on the tr.id `The multi-part identifier "tr.id" could not be bound.`

Comment: @mrt . . . I added in the table name that you are using, which should fix the issue.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that didn't help, same error even if I cut out all lines after tr.id

Comment: @mrt . . . The sample data in your question has a column called `id`.  I don't know why your query would not see it.

Comment: hmm, maybe I got your statements wrong. Initially I thought that `t` was your table name. But now, after you inserted `myTable` I am confused. If I write the code like you, it almost fails at `update t` because `t` is not known... If I specify `myTable` instead of `t`, it fails at the `tr.id`. Is `myTable t` some sort of alias notation? I just know of `table AS t`

Comment: @mrt . . . `t` is an alias for your table.  SQL Server supports aliases for `update` when they are defined in the `from` clause.  I see no reason to be confused.

Comment: hmm, if I remove the semikolon after `tr.ID` i do not get any errors. does the semikolon break the alias notation for the update clause?

Comment: @mrt . . . Ouch.  That was a typo.  The semicolon should never have been there.

Comment: alright, now it works. There's another little error in your first code block, you are not switching columns. If I change `Col1, Col2` to `Col2, Col1` in the `INSERT` or `SELECT`-statement, it works as intended, maybe you can update this so this is a fully correct answer. thx

Comment: @mrt . . . Is there a reason why you don't think this is "fully correct"?  I notice you unaccepted it.

Comment: no it is fully correct, but I go for the UNION view, so I marked Seans comment as "answer", unfortunately I had to unmark your comment, though it is fully correct